# Как верстаются такие менюшки?

Tags: вёрстка

Добрый день!
Подскажите, как верстаются такие менюшки?[image: верстка]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
nav {
  background-color: #eee;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000000;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 120px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 2(наведи)</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Меню 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню 2.3 (наведи)</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Меню 2.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Меню 2.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Меню 2.3.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Реализация на чистом css.